# Send different confirmation emails with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I need to send different confirmation emails while using Devise.

So, when a user signs up from subdomain they receive a different confirmation email, and when a user signs up from the root domain, they receive a different email.

How can I achieve this?

Edit:

I created MyDeviceMailer

```
class MyDeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  layout 'mailers'

  # To make sure that your mailer uses the devise views
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer' 

 def confirmation_instructions(record, token, options={})
   # Use different e-mail templates for signup e-mail confirmation 
   #   and for when a user changes e-mail address.
   if request.subdomain?
     options[:template_name] = 'confirmation_instructions_sub'
   else
     options[:template_name] = 'confirmation_instructions'
   end
   super
  end
end
```

and in my devise.rb file I added

config.mailer = 'MyDeviseMailer'

Comment: Can you show us what you tried already?

Comment: Added what I did so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally solved this issue. Instead of getting into all these complexities, simply replace your confirmation link with

```
<%= link_to 'Confirm my account', user_confirmation_url(confirmation_token: @token, subdomain: Apartment::Tenant.current) %>
```